# Moving arrow functions into another file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, arrow-functions, asyncstorage

I'm writing a react-native app, in which I'm using asyncStorage. Following the recommendations of the docs, I tried using the following wrapper functions:

```
_storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', 'I like to save it.');
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};
```

And similar ones for retrieving and deleting keys.

This was working fine, but as you can imagine, these functions are used a lot, so having a copy of them in each file is unmanageable. I created a 'utils.js' file, and rewrote the functions like this:

```
export async function _storeData(key, data) {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR SAVING");
  }
}
```

And in the code, instead of using `this._storeData(key,data)` as before, I used:

```
import { _storeData } from "../utils";
...
_storeData(key, data)
```

This does not throw an error, but never seems to actually store, retrieve, or delete anything. I can confirm that when the functions were written as arrow functions within the same file, it worked perfectly.

I'm pretty new to this...

Would it make sense to leave them as arrow functions, and bind them?

Comment: `async`  function returns `Promise` so you should either subscribe to the `Promise` with `.then` or wrap in another `async` function with `await`

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan Thank you. I had already used .then on the retrieveData function (when it was an arrow function), in order to do something to with the retrieved data. I assumed that when storing data, I wouldn't need to actually do anything with the promise, as I didn't need it to return anything, just to store the data

Comment: is the `_storeData = ` prefixed with `var` or something, or did you accidentally create global variables there?

Comment: @Bergi Nope, the code is exactly as I've posted it, so I'm guessing I've made a mistake!

Comment: I don't know react-native, but where does `AsyncStorage` come from? Is it somehow file-scoped? Otherwise, yes these should work exactly the same. None of the [differences between function declarations and arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572) should matter to you.

Comment: From this, if it helps: import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

Comment: @Alex Ok, what happens if you put a `var` in the arrow function version?

Comment: @Alex It might help if you could make a [mcve] of the non-working code, and the same example with working code

Comment: I can give it a go...

Comment: You might try building a small [expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/)...it can help others run/test your react native code

Comment: You don't need an async function. A simple function would do the job.

Comment: @10101010 Why does the facebook example use async then?